# Coordinates of the linear function in dual space.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Assume we have dual basis {$\phi_1,\phi_2, \phi_3 $} in $V^*$ of basis {$v_1, v_2, v_3$} in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How can i find coordinates of the function $f(x) = x_1 - x_2 + 4x_3$ in basis {$\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3$}.

Comment: I assume you want $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3\}$ to be the dual basis of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$? Then we still need to know what $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is. But the procedure could be to write $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_3$ down as functions and try to express $f$ as a linear combination. Then solve the linear equation system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f=b_1\phi_1+b_2\phi_2+b_3\phi_3$. Since $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3\}$ is the dual basis of $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, the following holds
$$
\phi_i(v_j)=
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } i=j\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then go to compute $f(v_1)$. $v_1$ has coordinates $(1,0,0)$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, hence $f(v_1)=1$. On the other hand, $f(v_1)=b_1$, hence $b_1=1$. A similar reasoning applied to $v_2$ and $v_3$ tells you that $b_2=-1$ and $b_3=4$.

Hence, $$f=\phi_1-\phi_2+4\phi_3$$

Comment: You assume that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is the standard basis?

Comment: No, I don't. If $\mathcal{B}$ is any ordered basis of $\Bbb R^3$ and $v_1$ is the first vector, then its coordinates wrt $\mathcal{B}$ are $(1,0,0)$. Similarly, $v_2$ has coorindates $(0,1,0)$ and $v_3$ has coordinates $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Ok, then you assume that $f$ is given in the basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that. If $f$ were written in the standard basis there is no explicit way to write $f$ as linear combination of $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$.